# Connecting to Windows NAS devices: WD is accessible, but Buffalo LinkStation is not

Tags: mount, nas, smb, timeout

Running Ubuntu 18.04.2. I have two NAS devices on my (Windows) workgroup. Ubuntu can connect to one of them (a WD MyCloud) with the SMB protocol smb://mywdshare/share, but the other NAS (Buffalo LinkStation), using smb://mylinkstation/share, returns a "Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out" error. I've made the most commonly suggested changes

```
sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
client max protocol = SMB3
```

but they don't make any difference. I've tried accessing the share both using Nautilus and a terminal, with the same result. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Set 'vers=3.0' in the relevant line in `/etc/fstab` or as an option to `mount`. See https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFSKernel#Linux_Kernel_SMB3.2FCIFS_Client

`/etc/samba/smb.conf` is for Samba, which you're not using here.